# Using Imaginary Numbers to Find Solutions to Indefinite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

I recently was solving an indefinite integral and via $u-$substitution arrived at the form: $$\int\frac{du}{u^2-a^2}$$
Knowing,

> $$\int\frac{du}{u^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{b}\arctan{\frac{u}{b}}+C$$

Is it a valid solution to let: $b=ai$, and therefore have the result: $$\int\frac{du}{u^2-a^2}=\frac{1}{ai}\arctan\frac{u}{ai}+C$$
I assume that since $i$ is just a constant the solution is valid.

Comment: It is valid, but probably not what the instructor is looking for in a calculus class.  You need to know a little bit of complex variables to simplify this to a real form: $- \dfrac{1}{a} \text{arctanh} \dfrac{u}{a} + C$.

Comment: That's what I figured. This question isn't for any class, I just was wondering if my approach was appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: [This Mathematics Educators SE answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/27110/745) may be of interest.